# Vendor directory not found

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I am trying to build a Docker image using the below Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.1-fpm

# Install server packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
     htop \
     nano \
     mc \
     wget \
     cron \
     bzip2 \
     optipng \
     jpegoptim \
     imagemagick \
     supervisor \
     # for php extensions
     libpq-dev \
     libzip-dev \
     libfreetype6-dev \
     libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
     libmcrypt-dev \
     libpng12-dev \
     libmagickwand-dev

# Install php packages
RUN docker-php-source extract \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install pgsql pdo_pgsql bcmath zip gd mcrypt opcache \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

WORKDIR /app
COPY src /app

RUN usermod -u 1001 www-data \
    && chown -R www-data .

# Setup
COPY env/docker/app/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
COPY env/docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/

COPY env/docker/app/crontab /var/app/
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/cron
RUN crontab /var/app/crontab

COPY env/docker/app/starter.sh /var/app/

RUN chmod 777 /var/app

ENTRYPOINT ["/var/app/starter.sh"]
```

I am then pushing the created docker image to a RedHat Openshift environment that we use.

When I load the web application however, I get the following error

`Warning: require(/app/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /app/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17`

When I examine the pod on OpenShift, there is no Vendor directory, so it appears the composer hasn't worked properly. Any ideas?

If relevant, I am doing the docker build on my Windows 7 machine using Vagrant and Centos 7.

Comment: If you have an SSH connection available to this server, run : `composer -v` to ensure composer is installed, and then run `composer update` on your project folder.

Comment: Hmmm, `composer -v` gives `composer not found`, which suggests the install didn't work properly in the docker build.

When I try to install the composer from the pod in OpenShift, it's not allowing me access to /usr/bin to do the install.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This docker image have to be built with your app with dependencies installed.The dependencies here are composer packages. So, before building your image, you have to execute command

> composer install

in the directory which contains file **composer.json**.

Then you build your docker image.

Comment: So simple...

Will try that a bit later!

Answer (score 2):

You need to run the `composer install` command from inside the project.

You installed the composer binary but not the packages ;)